# How do I do this using SQL Joins?

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp

I think I can do this using Joins? How? Xampp doesn't respond when I use this one. It doesn't even show errors, just doesn't do anything. Works with other queries.

```
SELECT * 
FROM acw_papers_web
WHERE id_paper_web IN (SELECT id_paper_web FROM acw_papers_web_autores 
WHERE nombre_autor_pw LIKE '%$autor%')
```

Comment: Please accept your answer before asking, you have asked a a lot of question without accept it as an answer. You can accept by clicking the check mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) like this:

```
SELECT web.* FROM acw_papers_web web
INNER JOIN acw_papers_web_autores aut
ON web.id_paper_web = aut.id_paper_web
WHERE aut.nombre_autor_pw LIKE '%$autor%'
```